# Maintaining openVPN connection on CentOS 7 Server

Tags: bash, openvpn, centos7, networkmanager

Morning all,

I have a headless CentOS 7 server that has an openVPN tunnel to another server at a different location.  I have looked around the net and found that if I place a script inside the `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` that I can call that script and initiate a tunnel between the two sites.

This worked well but I am finding that the tunnel is dropping out from time to time and not automatically coming back up.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$2" in
  up)
    if [ "$CONNECTION_ID" == "ens192" ]; then
      systemctl start openvpn-client@client
    fi
  ;;
  down)
    systemctl stop openvpn-client@client
  ;;
esac
```

Call it using `CONNECTION_ID=ens192 /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/10-openvpn ens192 up`

How do I get the system to bring the tunnel back up again if it goes down?

Cheers in advance,

Comment: First, find out why the tunnel is going down.

Comment: you should check the client log. it might be `TLS: tls_process: killed expiring key`. if thats the case you should use the --reneg-sec <time> options